# image in Frame by Frame animation from URL

Tags: android

As we know Frame by Frame animation are made by multiple images.and images are comeing from drawable folder.
**Like this:**

```
 <animation-list xmlns:android=
    "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/renew20001" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/renew20002" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/renew20003" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/renew20004" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/renew20005" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Now i get images from particular url.and display animation.is it possible or not?
if yes then provide solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure you will be able to load image from elsewhere than drawable folder
here is my cooked up version.

```
private static final int DELAY = 500;
Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(getNewBitmap());
        myImageView.postDelayed(changeImage, DELAY);
    }
};
```

in you onResume

```
myImageView.postDelayed(changeImage, DELAY);
```